# Setting a OnClickListener in a loop

Tags: java, android

I am trying to set a `OnClickListener` to a image in a loop. If the params platform is "android" then use market app, instead of default browswer. Is there a better solution to my exception handling or eliminatingsome of the `if-else` ?

```
private void setupListener(ImageView image, final String platform,
        final String urlLink) {
    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase(PLATFORM_ANDROID)) {
                // open with market app
                String packageName = extractPackageName(urlLink);
                if (packageName != null) {
                    try {
                        Intent market = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        market.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="
                                + packageName));
                        activity.startActivity(market);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        startInBroswer(urlLink);
                    }
                } else {
                    startInBroswer(urlLink);
                }

            } else {
                // open with default broswer.
                startInBroswer(urlLink);
            }

        }
    });
}

private void startInBroswer(String urlLink) {
    Intent browser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlLink));
    activity.startActivity(browser);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another version with [guard clauses](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html):

```
private void setupListener(final ImageView image, final String platform, 
        final String urlLink) {
    image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!platform.equalsIgnoreCase(PLATFORM_ANDROID)) {
                startInBroswer();
                return;
            }

            final String packageName = extractPackageName(urlLink);
            if (packageName == null) {
                startInBroswer();
                return;
            }

            try {
                final Intent market = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                market.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName));
                activity.startActivity(market);
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                // TODO: log the exception
                startInBroswer();
            }
        }

        private void startInBroswer() {
            final Intent browser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                Uri.parse(urlLink));
            activity.startActivity(browser);
        }
    });
}
```

Two things to notice:

1. I've removed the `urlLink` parameter of the `startInBroswer` method.
2. It is a [bad idea to use `printStackTrace()` in Android exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3855187/843804).

Answer (score 2):

Define field listener and assign it as OnClick handler.
You'll have only one object.

```
View.OnClickListener mListener

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mListener = new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (platform.equalsIgnoreCase(PLATFORM_ANDROID)) {
                // open with market app
                String packageName = extractPackageName(urlLink);
                if (packageName != null) {
                    try {
                        Intent market = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        market.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="
                                + packageName));
                        activity.startActivity(market);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        startInBroswer(urlLink);
                    }
                } else {
                    startInBroswer(urlLink);
                }

            } else {
                // open with default broswer.
                startInBroswer(urlLink);
            }

        }
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

private void setupListener(ImageView image, final String platform,
        final String urlLink) {
    image.setOnClickListener(mListener);
}
```

Comment: Nice tip. Thanks but it doesn't solve the problem with the clauses which I am more concerned about.